# Drawing text along a linestring

Tags: text, line, openlayers-3

I want to draw a text along a LineString. The text should be displayed parallel to the linestring. 
When i add a `ol.style.Text` to the style of the LineString, the text is shown, but it is not displayed parallel to the line.
Is there a possibility to get the letters "inside" the linestring?

Here you can see an example how it should look like: http://w3.outdooractive.com/map/xPiste/16/34166/23329.png?project=outdooractive

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible. The closer you may get is to place the text with rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Labelling text along line strings is a planned feature, but not yet available. For now, you could create a style function that calculates the angle of one segment of the line string and place a rotated label on a point near the center of that segment.

Comment: Would it be helpful if i open a new issue on the github repository?